# Switch statement using text box within forms

Tags: c#, switch-statement

> I am building a form that takes an input number from a text box and then will take the number that was input, and display the roman numeral equivalent in another text box.

My Form:

[image]

```
private void convertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int numberInput;
        switch (numberInput)
```

> This is where I keep getting an error code. The "switch (numberInput)" is seen as and unassigned local variable. How do I assign it so that it will be able to access all of the case integers?

```
        {
            case 1:
                outputTextBox.Text = "I";
                break;
            case 2:
                outputTextBox.Text = "II";
                break;
            case 3:
                outputTextBox.Text = "III";
                break;
            case 4:
                outputTextBox.Text = "IV";
                break;
            case 5:
                outputTextBox.Text = "V";
                break;
            case 6:
                outputTextBox.Text = "VI";
                break;
            case 7:
                outputTextBox.Text = "VII";
                break;
            case 8:
                outputTextBox.Text = "VIII";
                break;
            case 9:
                outputTextBox.Text = "IX";
                break;
            case 10:
                outputTextBox.Text = "X";
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter and number between 1 and 10. Thank you!");
                break;


        }
```

Comment: you need to assign `numberInput`

Comment: Side note: put all roman numbers into an array: `string[] romans = new[] {"I", "II", ..., "X"};` and address it instead of `switch..case`: `outputTextBox.Text = romans[numberInput - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

Cause your variable is not assigned yet `int numberInput;` and so the error. You said input is coming from a TextBox, in that case do like below assuming `textbox1` is your TextBox control instance name

```
int numberInput = Convert.ToInt32(this.textbox1.Text.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert.ToInt32 may throw an exception if the parsing is unsuccessful. Another method is to Int.Parse:

```
int numberInput = int.Parse(textbox1.Text.Trim());
```

or better yet

```
int numberInput;
if(int.TryParse(textbox1.Text.Trim(), out numberInput))
  {
      switch (numberInput) 
        ...

  }
```

Comment: Don't you mean to recommend `int.TryParse`?  `int.Parse` will also throw an exception if parsing is unsuccessful.